# Restoring broken Kali Live USB or Rescuing files?

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I was trying to update my Kali live usb with the feature that restarts kali and when it boots up again it updates not through the terminal with apt-get. The update stopped by itself before it was done causing my Kali live usb to break. Now I can boot into Kali but I can't open anything or see any icons. If I try to open terminal it goes into the screen you usually get before the desktop appears when you boot up normally except it does nothing. The way I set up my live usb does not allow me to choose to boot into safe mode. I have some files that I really need to rescue if possible. What can I do to try to restore Kali or at least be able to access the filesystem and save those files?

Answer (score 0):

If it were me in this scenario, to save myself the headache, I would plug the USB into another computer or a virtual machine, and use a file browser to copy the files from the root (/root) or user directory (/home if you used it). You should be able to do this with any Linux distributions including Debian and Ubuntu. Then format the drive and create a new live USB. A fresh install can never hurt anyway.